# How to handle urls with nextjs and chakra-ui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

When we use react linkify directly with chakra-ui (eg.Text) components, we cannot handle the link.

**Problematic use case**

```
import Linkify from 'react-linkify';
import {Box, Text} from '@chakra-ui/react';

export default function Usage(){

return (
 <Linkify>
  <Text>https://stackoverflow.com</Text>
 </Linkify>
);

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is;

Create Linkify.js

**Linkify.js file:**

```
import { Link } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import ReactLinkify from 'react-linkify';

const componentDecorator = (href, text, key) => (
  <Link
    href={href}
    key={key}
    isExternal={true}
    color="blue.500"
    _focus={{ outline: 'none' }}
  >
    {text}
  </Link>
);

export const Linkify = (props) => {
  return <ReactLinkify {...props} componentDecorator={componentDecorator} />; };
```

Import new Linkify Component to the file.

**Usage**

```
import { Linkify } from './Linkify';
import { Text } from '@chakra-ui/react';

export default function Usage(){
 return(
 <Linkify>
  <Text>https://stackoverflow.com</Text>
 </Linkify>
 )
}
```

Problem Solved! Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

In the current version i.e. "^1.0.0-alpha", the support for properties is removed. You can either do like this:

```
import Linkify from 'react-linkify';

<Linkify componentDecorator={(decoratedHref, decoratedText, key) => (
    <a target="blank" href={decoratedHref} key={key}>
        {decoratedText}
    </a>
  )}
>
```

Else, downgrade to version "0.2.2". Then, you can change the properties of the Linkify component. Worked for me!

```
import Linkify from 'react-linkify';

<Linkify properties={{target: "_blank", style: {color: 'blue',
 textDecoration: "underline", fontWeight: 'bold'}}}>
```